# Elastic Search - example.com vs example

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl-py

We are using elastic search 5.6.9 to power the search on our Django 1.11 server.

If I am indexing data `example.com` and searching for `example.com` I get the search result, but if I am searching for `example` I don't get any search results.

Ideally, I want `example` and `example.com` both to work and give back the same search result.

How can I go about getting this behaviour?

I thought that I will have to change the analyzer and tokenizer for the same.

Using `simple` analyzer seems like the right thing to do.
Ex:

`POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "simple",
  "text": "example.com"
}`

returns `example` and `com` as separate tokens

`{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "example",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "com",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}`

I think that I have to set the same analyzer/tokenizer while indexing data and on the query while searching.

I tried setting the `analyzer` to `simple` as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analyzer.html
However, now I still have to search for `example.com` instead of `example`, plus NOW I don't see anything in the `highlight` of the search result.

I am confused as to how this is resulting in a search result but not into `highlight`.

Am I completely off base here?

Comment: Hi, is there a mapping https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html ? Possible you do not index/search with "simple"-analyzer. 
Try the analyzer-API with specific index and without "analyzer"-parameter. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/indices-analyze.html

Comment: @KarstenR. Here is my mapping.
```
{
"my_index": {
"mappings": {
"record": {
"date_detection": false,
"properties": {
"fields": {
"properties": {
"a0g8dfdrpm": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "simple"
},
"a0of86vs7k": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "simple"
},
"apemix41h6": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "simple"
},
"b0j9j69qou": {
"type": "text",
"analyzer": "simple"
}
.......
}}}}}}}
```
I am not sure what you mean by trying analyzer api with specific index and without "analyzer" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example would be helpful for you:

#### Mapping

```
PUT /so54071449
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "type": "text",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
          "fields": {
            "simple": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "simple",
              "search_analyzer": "simple",
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Add document

```
POST /so54071449/doc
{
  "url": "example.com"
}
```

#### Search by `example`

```
GET /so54071449/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "example",
      "fields": ["url", "url.simple"]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "url": {
        "matched_fields": [
          "url",
          "url.simple"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result by `example`

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.25811607,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so54071449",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AWgoEwDT2HOwokHu0yvd",
        "_score": 0.25811607,
        "_source": {
          "url": "example.com"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "url": [
            "<em>example</em>.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Search by `example.com`

```
GET /so54071449/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "example.com",
      "fields": ["url", "url.simple"]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "url": {
        "matched_fields": [
          "url",
          "url.simple"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result by `example.com`

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.51623213,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so54071449",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AWgoEwDT2HOwokHu0yvd",
        "_score": 0.51623213,
        "_source": {
          "url": "example.com"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "url": [
            "<em>example.com</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've used [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/multi-fields.html) to apply two analyzers (`standard`, which is a default, on `url` field and `simple` on `url.simple` sub-field) and [`matched_fields` to combine highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-highlighting.html) results from `url` and `url.simple` into one field.

Comment: Can I use `_all` with `match` instead of `multi_match` and listing all the fields. I am asking because the list of fields can be above 1000 and it is dynamic. Sending this list in the payload results in an error of payload being too large.
Can I use `_all` while also specifying to use all the sub-fields?

Comment: Yes, you can. For highlighting on `_all` field read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html. Please remember that `_all` was deprecated in 6.0.0. But maybe it is not a problem for you.

Comment: Using `_all` with `match` doesn't give any search results. I guess it's because it is only searching in `url` and not in `url.simple`.

I tried like this:
```
GET /so54071449/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "example"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "_all": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: True. I missed that. It is possible to query with wildcard `"query": {"multi_match": {"query": "example","fields": ["url*"]}}` but still it is probably not an option in your case.